# Samsung GT 7.7 hung after charging

Tags: charging, system-freeze, samsung-galaxy-tab-7.7

After charging my Samsung GT 7.7, I switched it on but it just showed the "Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.7" and stayed like that like it hung.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

If it has a removable battery, remove the battery, put it back and run it. Else wait for it to discharge then charge and turn it back on. If none of these solve your problem, boot to the Recovery Menu and factory reset your device.

Comment: battery can't be removed. I tried to charge it after 10 hrs that incident happened, it didn't charge and the battery became hot. An advise was to go to a Samsung service center. I heard it's not covered by the warranty. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Did you try factory data reseting your device?

Comment: How sir? I can't switch it on. It won't even switch on even through USB.

Comment: Every device has a recovery menu. Google it to know how to access it for YOUR device. It involves holding a couple of buttons at boot so that it shows the recovery menu instead of the traditional boot up screen.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung devices have Download and Recovery modes with buttons combo to enter them. I don't know what it is for your tab, but usually for Samsung devices it's <kbd>vol up</kbd> + <kbd>home button</kbd> + <kbd>power button</kbd>. Make sure the device is off before doing so.

Once you enter Recovery, just factory reset the device. As long as it's bootable, this could make it work.